# I am following a tutorial with Sabastian Lague and Brackeys on an rpg game in Unity 3d, but the blender animation isn't working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, blender

Here is the link to episode: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COckHIIO8vk&list=PLPV2KyIb3jR4KLGCCAciWQ5qHudKtYeP7&index=4

I have triple checked all the animation and blender imports. I have imported it as a .fbx

Here is the animator pictures:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

I am not sure if this is an issue with the code or the engine.

This is the C# code:

```
using System.Collections;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using UnityEngine;

using UnityEngine.AI;

public class CharacterAnimator : MonoBehaviour
{   
    const float locomotionAnimationSmoothTime = .1f;

    NavMeshAgent agent;
    Animator animator;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        agent = GetComponent<NavMeshAgent>();
        animator = GetComponentInChildren<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float speedPercent = animator.velocity.magnitude / agent.speed;
        
        animator.SetFloat("speedPercent", speedPercent, locomotionAnimationSmoothTime, Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what "isn't working" means? What does or does not happen?

Comment: The animation isn't showing anything. Its just a player moving

Comment: You need to show us your animator as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have put pictures of the animator, I am very new to unity. Thank you for trying to solve my problem

Comment: I have just realized that the animation is working but when I move it's still in idle animation.